# Different apps with same code base in iOS

Tags: ios, ipa

I am developing an iOS app. Client needs a app for each city as there might be different functionalities for each city. One way is to upload multiple ipa files with different app name, bundle id. Is there any another way?Is there anything similar to build flavours in android gradle for iOS?

Comment: You can **not** use one bundle ID and name for different apps. You can use targets to use on code base for different apps. But be aware that Apple does want you to upload many apps that have the same functionality under different names. 

You might just want to offer a city selection option in your app to all the user to switch between cities.

Comment: @rckoenes thank you i will try it with different targets

Comment: @rckoenes so can an app while running change targets depending on user input??

Comment: No, a target is build of you app with specific settings, like different Bundle ID, name, resources, etc...

Comment: ok so i have to upload different ipa files with different targets right?

Comment: Yes, each target is it's own app.